# Can we link SQL scripts inside other SQL script in MySQL?

Tags: sql, automation, mysql

In Oracle database, we can link SQL scripts inside other SQL script like this:

```
@@ drop.sql
```

Is it possible to do similar in MySQL database?

Basically, I want to automate whole database installation by creating new tables, constraints and basic data.
For that, it would be good to maintain different type of SQL statements in different SQL scripts/files.

But to install database, we should run run only one SQL script, which should be pointing other SQL scripts from inside.

Also want to do it without any other programming language.
It would be better to do it with SQL script only (like Oracle supports).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, using the command `source` (which short form is `\.`). Example:

script1.sql

```
SELECT 'First hello from script1';
source script2.sql;
SELECT 'Second hello from script1';
```

script2.sql

```
SELECT 'Hello from script2';
```

Calling script1.sql:

```
$ mysql -s < script1.sql
First hello from script1
Hello from script2
Second hello from script1
```

More info here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-commands.html

Comment: Thanks @Muur, it's working. but one thing is, I have to mention everywhere absolute path for all links. There are many nested sql scripts linked, so is there a way to change current working directory after logged in to MySQL console?

Comment: I don't think it is possible after. You can do it *before* with one command: `cd /path/to/your/scripts/ && mysql < script.sql`.